# how to add manually a legend to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend, symbols

I want to add manually a legend to ggplot in r. The problem of my code is that it does not show the right symbols (blue point, blue dashed line and red solid line). Here the code and the plot.

```
predict_ID1.4.5.6.7 <- predict(lm_mRNATime, ID1.4.5.6.7)
ID1.4.5.6.7$predicted_mRNA <- predict_ID1.4.5.6.7
colors <- c("data" = "Blue", "predicted_mRNA" = "red","fit"="Blue")
ggplot( data = ID1.4.5.6.7, aes(x=Time,y=mRNA,color="data")) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c('0','20','40','60','120'))+
  labs(title="ID-1,ID-4,ID-5,ID-6,ID-7",y="mRNA", x="Time [min]", color = "Legend") +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors)+
  geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=predicted_mRNA,color="predicted_mRNA"),lwd=1.3)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",aes(color="fit",lty=2),se=TRUE,lty=2)+
  scale_color_manual(values = colors)+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

How can I modify the code in order to get the symbols associated to the plot in the legend ?

Comment: Could you please include some data to make your question reproducible?

Comment: This could be achievd via `guide_legend`. Try e.g. `+ guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, NA, NA), linetype = c("blank", "dashed", "solid"))))`. See e.g. [ggplot2 add manual legend for two data series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688799/ggplot2-add-manual-legend-for-two-data-series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardest part here was recreating your data set for demonstration purposes. It's always better to add a reproducible example. Anyway, the following should be close:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

ID1.4.5.6.7 <- data.frame(Time = c(rep(1, 3), 
                                   rep(c(2, 3, 4, 5), each = 17)),
                          mRNA = c(rnorm(3, 0.1, 0.25), 
                                   rnorm(17, 0, 0.25),
                                   rnorm(17, -0.04, 0.25), 
                                   rnorm(17, -0.08, 0.25),
                                   rnorm(17, -0.12, 0.25)))

lm_mRNATime <- lm(mRNA ~ Time, data = ID1.4.5.6.7)
```

Now we run your code with the addition of a custom colour guide:

```r
predict_ID1.4.5.6.7 <- predict(lm_mRNATime, ID1.4.5.6.7)
ID1.4.5.6.7$predicted_mRNA <- predict_ID1.4.5.6.7

colors <- c("data" = "Blue", "predicted_mRNA" = "red", "fit" = "Blue")

p <-  ggplot( data = ID1.4.5.6.7, aes(x = Time, y = mRNA, color = "data")) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = predicted_mRNA, color = "predicted_mRNA"), 
                  lwd = 1.3) +
        geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(color = "fit", lty = 2), 
                    se = TRUE, lty = 2) +
        scale_x_discrete(limits = c('0', '20', '40', '60', '120')) +
        scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
        labs(title = "ID-1, ID-4, ID-5, ID-6, ID-7", 
             y = "mRNA", x = "Time [min]", color = "Legend") +
        guides(color = guide_legend(
                       override.aes = list(shape = c(16, NA, NA), 
                                           linetype = c(NA, 2, 1)))) +
        theme(plot.title    = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
              plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
              legend.key.width = unit(30, "points"))
```

[image]